# Adapt content to QHBoxLayout size, and allow user resizing

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have issues doing a widget with pyQt, I hope you will be able to help me:

My widget is basically a `QHBoxLayout`, featuring a spacer and a little button "more".

When this button is clicked, a new window is opened (with a `QGridLayout` inside). No problems on this side.

The `QHBoxLayout` size is given by the widget size, which depend on the main window size. This size can be tuned by the user.

example app featuring my widget

[image]

Now what I want to do is adding some buttons (I don't know how many : this number can vary) in the `QHBoxLayout` as long as there is enough space in it, then adding them in the other window.

Adding the buttons should not resize the main window.
If the user resize the window, the buttons should flow either in the `QHBoxLayout` if the user enlarge the window, or in the `QGridLayout` if the user shrink the window.

Right now, I don't know how to get the available space in the `QHBoxLayout` so I can't adapt how many buttons I should put in it. If I add too many buttons, the widget size increase, and so the main window size.

I get `QResizeEvent`s when I enlarge the main window so I could move buttons from the `QGridLayout` into the `QHBoxLayout`, but I don't have these events if I try to shrink the window.

Can you help me with that ?

Thank you.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: I tried to get the spacer size with `sizeHint()` but when I print it, I get "empty" QSize: `PyQt5.QtCore.QSize()`.
If I call this method on an other item (e.g. the button on the right) I get for example : `PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(22, 24)`